# Populate Textview from Firebase. Error: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Was looking for what I was doing wrong for quite some time, hope can find some help here. I am trying to populate text view from Firebase.

```
private TextView txtDetails;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
private String userId;
private EditText inputLastName;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gb_personal_profile);

    txtDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_profile_name);

    mFirebaseDatabase = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            gbCreationUNameDB user = 
dataSnapshot.getValue(gbCreationUNameDB.class);


            txtDetails.setText(user.first_name);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

and here is the User

```
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class gbCreationUNameDB {
public String first_name;
public String last_name;


public gbCreationUNameDB() {
}

public gbCreationUNameDB(String first_name, String last_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getfirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}
}
```

Help greatly appreciated. Already checked all resources, cant figure it out

Comment: It seems "userId" is null when you are trying to call mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId)...

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the object of `gbCreationUNameDB class` from the dataSnapshot object, you are using this line of code:

```
txtDetails.setText(user.first_name);
```

Which means that you are trying to get the value of the `first_name` field  directly, but this approach is wrong. To get that value, you need to use the public getter like this:

```
txtDetails.setText(user.getfirst_name());
```

Second, in  your `DatabaseReference` there is only one element which can be null and this is `userId`. As i can see in your code, you aren't getting this element from anywhere. So to get the user uid, please use the following code:

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (firebaseUser != null) {
    String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have tried, but somehow still getting the same error